# Como retornar uma mensagem de dado que não atende uma condição em laço de repetição?

Tags: c, condição

Boa noite, pessoal! Estou estudando linguagem C por conta e, para treinar, estou tentando codificar um programa que leia entradas de parâmetros metalúrgicos (liga, têmpera e espessura) para que um valor de raio para ensaio de dobramento seja retornado para o usuário. Pois bem: consegui codificar um trecho de código com laço de repetição para avaliar os parâmetros passados pelo usuário, determinando se são válidos para o ensaio de dobramento ou não. Até agora, eu consegui filtrar a liga, conseguindo determinar se ela entra ou não, no grupo de ligas que pedem ensaio de dobramento, mas não estou conseguindo filtrar a têmpera. O código segue abaixo:

```
for (cont=0; cont<=3;cont++){ //contador para comparação com as ligas cadastradas
    if (liga1==liga[cont]){
        for (cont=0; cont<=6;cont++){ //contador para comparação com as têmperas cadastradas
            if (strcmp(temp1,temp[cont])==0){
                printf ("\nDobramento exigido para a liga %d e têmpera %s, na espessura %.3fmm na Norma ASTM!\n", liga1, temp1, esp1);
                if (esp1>=esp[0] && esp1<esp[1]){
                    printf ("\n\nO raio de dobramento é 'x'!\n");
                } else if (esp1>=esp[1] && esp1<esp[2]){
                    printf ("\n\nO raio de dobramento é 'y'!\n");
                } else if (esp1>=esp[2]){
                    printf ("\n\nO raio de dobramento é 'z'!\n");
                }
            } else if (strcmp(temp1, temp[cont])!=0){ //AQUI ESTÁ A MINHA DIFICULDADE!!!
                if (cont==6)
                printf ("\nTêmpera sem dobramento!\n");
            }
        }
    } else if (liga1!=liga[cont]){ /*Se a liga não for igual a nenhuma liga cadastrada, retorna
    msg, essa condição é verifica antes da têmpera, se retornar verdadeiro, o programa nem avalia
    a têmpera e a espessura*/
        if (cont == 3){
            printf ("Liga não contemplada com ensaio de dobramento na Norma ASTM!\n\a");
        }
    }
}
```

Coloquei o comentário "AQUI ESTÁ MINHA DIFICULDADE", na linha do código em que estou tendo problemas. Eu preciso que essa linha do código retorne "Têmpera sem dobramento" para o usuário apenas quando a têmpera não for igual a nenhuma têmpera cadastrada previamente na variável temp (vetor de strings). Acontece que na execução do código, ele até retorna a mensagem corretamente em caso de têmpera diferente das que foram cadastradas, mas também está mostrando quando o usuário digita uma têmpera válida (aparecendo a mensagem "Têmpera sem dobramento" depois da mensagem de "Dobramento exigido, etc...")! Podem me ajudar, por gentileza?

Não sei se estou usando o método correto para tal fim (esse tipo de laço de repetição), então fico aberto a sugestões e críticas, afinal elas são bem vindas no aprendizado!

Comment: Você está utilizando a mesma variável para índice de liga e para índice de têmperas, que está dentro do laço da primeira. Utilize variáveis diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma seria você criar uma função de busca que retorne true ou false:

```
boolean busca(TIPO_AQUI temp1,TIPO_AQUI temp)
{
    for (cont=0; cont<=6;cont++)
        if (strcmp(temp1,temp[cont])==0)
            return true;    
    return false;
}
```

Assim você usaria da seguinte forma:

```
else if (!busca(temp1,temp))
    printf ("\nTêmpera sem dobramento!\n");
```

Alguns detalhes do seu código devem ser alterados:

1. A mesma variável **cont**=0 esta sendo usada em dois laços, teoricamente como um laço esta dentro do outro, isso pode afetar o seu código.

Sugiro então a renomeação das variáveis.

Comment: Filipe, continuei tentando codificar na base da raça mesmo e, embora eu creia que possa deixar o código um pouco mais clean com o tempo, consegui resolver a questão de outra forma. Fiz uma outra estrutura para validação dos dados, que deu super certo (pelo menos, o funcionamento geral). Ainda tem algumas questões pendentes que tentarei solucionar, se eu não conseguir, pedirei ajuda dos usuários do site. Mas obrigado, mesmo assim...

Answer (score 0):

Galera, eu consegui resolver o problema alterando a estrutura de validação dos dados fornecidos pelo usuário. Fiz um menu usando a função switch, onde ele entra com o a opção da norma a ser usada para pesquisar o valor do raio exigido para dobramento na análise do material (isso após ele entrar com os dados de liga, têmpera e espessura). Uma vez escolhida a norma, eu avalio o grupo a que pertence a liga do material (grupo 3XXX ou 5XXX) e redireciono a execução do programa para uma função correspondente (considerando a norma solicitada e o grupo da liga do material). Por exemplo, a função para a liga 3XXX na norma ASTM segue abaixo:

```
float astm_3xxx(float r, char lg_3xxx[6], char t_3xxx[4], float e_3xxx){
int cont, cont1; //contadores para comparação entre ligas
int cnt, cnt1; //contadores para comparação entre têmperas

char lg1[3][6]={"3004", "3104", "3105"}; /*primeiro índice indica a qtde de ligas e o segundo
a quantidade de caracteres que poderão ser armazenados em cada liga/conteúdo*/
char tp1[5][4]={"H22", "H24", "H26", "H32", "H34"};

for (cont=0;cont<=3;cont++){ //percorrendo os índices de liga
    for (cont1=0;cont1<=4;cont1++){//percorrendo os caracteres de cada índice
        if (lg_3xxx[cont1]==lg1[cont][cont1]){
            cont1++;
            if (lg_3xxx[cont1]==lg1[cont][cont1]){
                cont1++;
                if (lg_3xxx[cont1]==lg1[cont][cont1]){
                    cont1++;
                    if (lg_3xxx[cont1]==lg1[cont][cont1]){
                        for (cnt=0;cnt<=5;cnt++){//percorrendo os índices de têmpera
                            for (cnt1=0;cnt1<=4;cnt1++){//percorrendo os caracteres de cada índice
                                if (t_3xxx[cnt1]==tp1[cnt][cnt1]){
                                    cnt1++;
                                    if (t_3xxx[cnt1]==tp1[cnt][cnt1]){
                                        cnt1++;
                                        if (t_3xxx[cnt1]==tp1[cnt][cnt1]){
                                          cnt1++;
                                          if (t_3xxx[cnt1]==tp1[cnt][cnt1]){
                                                  //TRATAMENTO DAS ESPESSURAS
                                                    if (e_3xxx <= 0.400){
                                                        r = 0;
                                                        printf ("\nEspessura abaixo do range que exige dobramento!\n");
                                                    } else if (e_3xxx > 0.400 && e_3xxx <=1.200){
                                                        r = 2.5;
                                                        return (r);
                                                    } else if (e_3xxx > 1.200 && e_3xxx <= 3.200){
                                                        r = 4.5;
                                                        return (r);
                                                    } else if (e_3xxx > 3.200){
                                                        r = 6.0;
                                                        return (r);
                                                    } 
                                            }  
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }    
                        }    
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Caso o usuário tenha informado uma liga 3004, por exemplo, será redirecionado para essa função, onde tenho armazenado algumas ligas num vetor de strings. Farei uma verificação da liga informada para ver se é uma das ligas cadastradas que exige dobramento na norma, percorrendo caracter por caracter, índice por índice. Caso true, comparo a têmpera com as têmperas cadastradas. Caso true, faço o tratamento para as espessuras e retorno o valor do raio para a função main() do programa. Caso a liga ou a têmpera não sejam iguais às cadastradas, a função vai devolver r = 0 para a função main(), então informarei ao usuário que o dobramento não é exigido para aquele material.

Estou estudando por conta, depois de longos anos sem estudar (não cheguei a trabalhar com programação, parando porque comecei a trabalhar longe da área de TI, antes mesmo de me inserir nesse mercado). Então creio que haja maneiras melhores para deixar o código mais clean, suponho. Caso alguém tenha alguma sugestão ou comentário, por favor, não se acanhem. Estou aqui para aprender!